# Bindings not updating despite PropertyChanged events successfully and properly thrown

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a page called *SubjectsPage*, the binding context of which is set to the *SubjectsPageViewModel*. Within that *SubjectsPage* is an *SfListView* control (Syncfusion) where its ItemsSource has been set to the *Subjects* ObservableCollection property, which is using the INotifyPropertyChanged pattern as follows:

```
        private ObservableCollection<Subject> _subjects;
        public ObservableCollection<Subject> Subjects
        {
            get => _subjects;
            set => SetProperty(ref _subjects, value, Subjects);
        }
```

**BaseViewModel:**

```
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public void SetProperty<T>(ref T property, T value, T publicProperty)
        {
            property = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(publicProperty));
        }
```

This same pattern is working absolutely fine in the page that is navigated to from one of the subjects on *SubjectsPage*. I have monitored the property notifications for the *Subject* model, and they are definitely thrown.

I created a test label that binds to a *TestInt* property in *SubjectsPageViewModel*, it also uses the property notification pattern above. In OnAppearing, I increment the value of this label to see whether it updates visually — it doesn't. The debug output writes the values each time so I can see where it should be, but this is not being visually reflected at all.

No bindings, though they are correct as the initial values do display, are updating in any part of the content on *SubjectsPage*.

**Setting the BindingContext for SubjectsPage**

```
        protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            if (Initialised is false)
                await SetContext();

            IncrementTest();
        }

        async Task SetContext()
        {
            BindingContext = await SubjectsPageViewModel.InitialiseAsync();
            Initialised = true;
        }
```

As above, my BindingContext is set in OnAppearing, as I needed to use async methods to initialise some backing properties that the view model properties are set to. Could setting it here create some kind of disconnect?

*SubjectsPage* inherits from *BasePage*, which inherits from ContentPage, as I needed an additional property for all my pages. This shouldn't affect anything, since the next page navigated to also inherits from this *BasePage*.

**SubjectsPage**

```
<views:BasePage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:xforms="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.ListView.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfListView.XForms"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:TraceIt.ViewModels"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:TraceIt.Models"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:TraceIt.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="TraceIt.Views.SubjectsPage"
             Title="Subjects"
             BackgroundColor="Black"
             x:Name="Page">

    //Styling and ToolbarItems

    <!--<views:BasePage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:SubjectsPageViewModel/>
    </views:BasePage.BindingContext>-->

    <views:BasePage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout Style="{DynamicResource gradientAbsoluteLayout}">

            
            <StackLayout Padding="0" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1">

                <Label Text="{Binding TestInt}" TextColor="White"/> // Test label (doesn't work)

                <xforms:SfListView x:Name="collectionViewSubjects" AutoFitMode="Height" 
                                   ItemSpacing="{OnIdiom Tablet=20, Phone=10}"
                                   SelectionMode="None" ItemsSource="{Binding Subjects}">

                    <xforms:SfListView.LayoutManager>
                        <xforms:GridLayout SpanCount="2"/>
                    </xforms:SfListView.LayoutManager>

                    <xforms:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate> // Not single binding here updates after property changes
                            
                                <Frame Style="{DynamicResource listItemFrame}" Padding="0">
                                    <StackLayout Padding="10, 13, 10, 20">

                                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                           Margin="0, 0, 0, 12"/>

                                        <Label Text="{Binding Credits, StringFormat='0 / {0} credits'}"/>

                                        <Label Text="{Binding StandardsCount, StringFormat='{0} standards'}" Margin="0, 0, 0, 12"/>

                                        <Button Text="View Info" CornerRadius="20"
                                                     TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                                     FontSize="17" Style="{DynamicResource subjectButtonGradient}"
                                                     Clicked="buttonViewInfo_Clicked" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                     WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="40"
                                                     VerticalOptions="End"/>

                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                            </SwipeView>
                            
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </xforms:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                    
                    

                </xforms:SfListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </views:BasePage.Content>
</views:BasePage>
```

**Example method where property is being modified:**

```
        private void SetCredits()
        {
            Credits = 0;

            foreach (var standard in Standards)
                AddStandardCredits(standard);
        }

        void AddStandardCredits(Standard standard)
        {
            if (standard.FinalGrade is Standard.Grade.Excellence)
                ExcellenceCredits += standard.Credits;
            else if (standard.FinalGrade is Standard.Grade.Merit)
                MeritCredits += standard.Credits;

            Credits += standard.Credits;
        }
```

**Snip of Subject model, one of the properties not being updated visually in SubjectsPage:**

```
public class Subject : BaseModel, ISubjectItem
```

```
        private int _credits;
        [NotNull]
        public int Credits
        {
            get => _credits;
            set => SetProperty(ref _credits, value, Credits);
        }
```

Feel free to ask for any other information that may help you answer.

Comment: where is the code for `Subject`?

Comment: I added a snippet, the SetProperty method is the same as the aforementioned. I don't believe the model is the problem, since my test label also fails to update when binding to a non-model related property.

Comment: that looks OK to me.  I don't know if SF may be doing some sort of default caching with their ListView that is different than the standard XF ListView

Comment: I haven't changed any caching settings, but the next page hasn't had any of that set either, but bindings do update correctly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, I figured out that the problem stemmed not from the ViewModels, nor the Models, but the BaseViewModel (and BaseModel). To make things easier for myself, I tried to use this syntax:

```
public void SetProperty<T>(ref T property, T value, T publicProperty)
        {
            property = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(publicProperty));
        }
```

The problem with this is that `nameof(publicProperty` does not give the name of the property that is passed in the parameter, but simply the local variable name, "publicProperty". So though the `PropertyChanged` event is raised, each time it is throwing with the wrong name, so the event subscribers to their respective properties are never reached.

I have modified my use of SetProperty where it now requires a string passed as the third parameter, where I will have to use `nameof()` each time.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, pkease do not forget to accept your answer, it will help others who have similar issue.